# regain access to centos7 after modify rc.local

Tags: virtual-machine, centos7

I have a centos 7 on a vm. I put some command lines on the rc.local to initialize always the system reboot. I think i did something wrong, because when i restart the system, it frozes and dont enter centos anymore.

The internet is not on, i have to manually connect it when the centos starts, so i can't login the machine through Putty or other ssh program in order to fix the rc.local

What should i do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer in this video:

```
www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvPtrwidhwo
```

When your linux appears to load completely (but get stuck) press "esc" to see where in the list of processes it got stuck.

Restart the virtual machine, and by the time it enters the mode to choose with linux you will want to load (rescue mode or normal mode), press ctrl+e to enter on a configuration/modification screen. It will show commands in the prompt.

You have to add parameters shown on the video. Search for the work "quiet". After this word and before the word LANG, add "systemd.unit=rescue.target"

Press ctrl+x to save (it will restart the vm automatic).

You will enter the rescue mode, input the root password.

Disable or modify the rc.local on (vi /etc/rc.local) in order to regain control over linux.

Then type: shutdown -r.

Restart the vm and everything will work again.